# Jmeter - loop an api based on a condition

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. I want to loop an api based on a condition. In the while controller I added the script as ${__javaScript("${response}"=="Please, wait while your order is being processed.")}

I added the http request sampler under this controller. The response I am getting from this request is

{"resp":"Please, wait while your order is being processed."}

I want to hit this api until I get this value in response.

I used regular expression extractor and provided the expression as "resp": "(.+?)" . But I am not getting this result and my loop is running continuosly. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to an extra space in your Regular Expression, looking into the response:

```
{"resp":"Please, wait while your order is being processed."}
```

There is no space between the semicolon and quotation mark, and in your regex:

```
"resp": "(.+?)"
       ^ here is the space character
```

Given regular expressions could be very fragile when it comes to working with JSON data I would recommend using one of the following Test Elements:

- [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) - if you using JMeter 3.0 or above
- [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - if you have to use earlier JMeter version for some reason.

In both cases the relevant JSON Path query will look like:

```
$.resp
```

References:

- [JSONPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thankyou.. I used the JSON Path Extractor and get the response. But the while loop is still running continuosly even if the condtion fails

Comment: You need to escape comma with the backslash like `${__javaScript("${response}"=="Please\, wait while your order is being processed.")}`. See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more detailed information in implementing "while" loops in JMeter tests